# Missing the UV island select mode?

Tags: interface, uv, selection-tools

I am trying to texture a flag pole model I made recently and after UV unwrapping it I tried to arrange the islands so they would be understandable.
However I couldn't find the island select mode, it just isn't there and I can't figure out why.

Can anyone tell me why this is and how I can fix it?

Comment: do you have the geo selected in edit mode?

Answer (score 6):

It is there in 2.70a for me.
In your question there is very little to go on;
However my guess would be that you have "Keep UV and Edit Mode mesh selection in Sync" active, this changes the selection modes that are available.

Sync selection off:

[image: Sync selection off]

Sync selection on:

[image: Sync selection on]

Comment: Thank you very much! I had no idea that could affect the options shown. As you can tell, i'm a very big noob to blender. Thanks again!

Comment: Don't feel bad, Nicolas. After using Blender for a few years now, this is without doubt one of the most irritating things I have ever dealt with. It was a long time before I ever figured this out, and I still find it highly unintuitive.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, Darren. This is still true in Blender 2.81. I had no idea what happened to island selection mode. The button should gray out, not disappear. That would be way less confusing! :-)